# Transformation of xy coordinates in logarithmic scale

Tags: matplotlib, transform

Here is a simple thing that I want to do

```
newcoords = ax.transLimits.transform( np.array(oldcoords)) )
```

in order to transform coordinates from the data coordinates `oldcoords` to the plot axis coordinates `newcoords`. My plot has one axis in linear scale, the other one in log scale. The component corresponding to the linear scale (e.g. `x`) is transformed correctly, but the component corresponding to the log scale (e.g. `y`) is not.

I tried this, but it doesn't work, how should I do it?

```
transInstance = ax.transLimits + ax.transScale
newcoords = transInstance.transform( oldcoords )
```

Comment: can you give a bit more context for what you are trying to do?  It seems like there should be an easier way to accomplish the end goal.

Comment: ok, but the context is a bit complicated and I don't think it's important: I have a plot created with `pcolormesh`, this plot has one axis in linear scale and another one in log scale, I find a minimum of this plot, and want to mark this minimum by drawing a rectangle in the place of the minimum, however, because of the log scale, the rectangle has ugly shape if I plot it in the data coordinates, therefore I want to draw it in the plot coordinates, i.e. to give it a readable data-independent size, and so I need this transform, which should be an easy thing to do, but I guess I do it wrong...

Comment: in short: I want to draw a rectangle centered on a chosen data region, but having size related to the size of the plot, e.g. having width and height equal to 5% of the plot, independently on where it is centered

Comment: you could do it in data-coordinates and just shift the center vertically so that the log of the distance of the edges above and below the point you want is equal

Comment: Can you not use individual axis scaling, via the ax.set_xscale and ax.set_yscale methods?http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xscale

Comment: What do you mean? What is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to the party, but I had troubles finding an answer after a lot of googling, so I think this might still help others.

The coordinates transformation has to occur in a slightly different manner; the transforms must be swapped or the two transformations must be nested. Note that this seems unnecessary if axis are linear instead of logarithmic.

For example take this plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Then if you want to transform the coordinates of the [10, 10] point, you must either nest the two transformations:

```
>>> ax.transLimits.transform(ax.transScale.transform([10, 10]))
array([1.        , 0.99800598])
```

or sum the transformations, but in the opposite order:

```
>>> newTransform = ax.transScale + ax.transLimits
>>> newTransform.transform([10, 10])
array([1., 1.])
```

Some more insights might be found in this other answer: [Annotate point offset by a fixed fraction of the Axes size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655568/annotate-point-offset-by-a-fixed-fraction-of-the-axes-size)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear about what transformations you are making to your data. Am I correct to assume you have data in the old coordinates x,y . You then transform to some new coordinates x' and y' and plot x' against log(y')?

If this is the case then when finding the minimum you will have a point in x'-log(y') space and you then need to draw a rectangle in these coordinates.

I apologise if I have misunderstood but I advise you to write down in full what transformations you make, and remember the order matters!

Comment: Um... It's much simpler than this ;)
I have x, y, and then plot y in log scale, so matplotlib does this transform for me: x'=x, y'=log(y). Then I find a point in x, y coordinates, and want to draw a rectangle, either in x', y' coordinates, or in the plot coordinates, which are basically equal to x', y'. I know that I can calculate the size of this rectangle manually, but there must be a simpler way of doing it using matplotlib commands.

Comment: Okay sorry I had misunderstood and thought you had two transformations. My apology.