# Annotate point offset by a fixed fraction of the Axes size

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create a set of `Axes.annotate()` in matplotlib. I would like these annotations to be offset from the point (akin to `textcoords='offset pixels'`) but in `‘axes fraction’` instead of absolute number of pixels.

The problem with using data coordinates, is that it gets messy when one uses logarithmic (or other) scales.

The problem with `offset pixels` is that the appearance changes if changing the size of the figure, or the dpi.

The following is an attempt to recapitulate the problem:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
axs[0].plot([1,2],[10,100])
axs[1].semilogy([1,2],[10,100])
for ax in axs:
    ax.annotate('', xy=(1,10), xytext=(1,50), textcoords=('data', 'offset pixels'),arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'-', 'lw':3})
plt.show()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, dpi=200)
axs[0].plot([1,2],[10,100])
axs[1].semilogy([1,2],[10,100])
for ax in axs:
    ax.annotate('', xy=(1,10), xytext=(1,50), textcoords=('data', 'offset pixels'),arrowprops={'arrowstyle':'-', 'lw':3})
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

I would like to have the annotation line be the same length (relative to the size of the plots), regardless of the size of the figure, or the scaling of the axes.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by looking through [Matplotlib's Transformation Tutoria](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html)l, which already contained everything I needed.

To plot something that was of constant length relative to the axes, I used the `Axes.transLimits` object. But before, I have to be wary of the possibility that I'm dealing with logarithmic axes, so I'll also use the `Axes.transScale` object to take the (possible) non-linear scaling of the axes into account.

The code that I'm using in the end is to get the 'Axes' coordinates of my initial point, and then simply plot from that point to a certain offset from that point, specifying that my coordinates are expressed in Axes coordinate system

```
xax,yax = ax.transLimits.transform(ax.transScale.transform([x,y]))
ax.plot([xax,xax], [y,y+offset], transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify the annotation offset in units of  axes fraction, just do it. The following produces the line of lentgh 20% axes fraction.

```
ax.annotate('', xy=(1,10), xytext=(1,0.2), textcoords=('data', 'axes fraction')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Using 'axes fraction' as you did specify that the y-coordinate of the end of the line should be at coordinate 20% of the axes height, which is NOT the same as to say the length of the line should be 20% tall, or am I mistaken?